# how to reverse print a tree path without recursion in C?

Tags: c, directory, nodes

I have a leaf node that stores it's parent node, it contains a data type of

```
const char *
```

which in this case is a string.
This tree of nodes represents a directory path. I'd like to print its path given a certain leaf node. I can't use recursion.

for example: if i'm given the node `foo`, and it's a level 3 node, my path printed should be something like

```
/level2/foo
```

since `/` represents the root (something is always printed. If I'm given the root node, then it should just print `/`).

What would be the most efficient algorithm for this? I can't concatenate strings the way I wanted to since it's in C.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ if you say you can only use C?

Comment: Sorry, noob here.

Comment: Why not use `strcat` as you traverse up?

Comment: Cuz I would have to store the concatenated strings in a string variable, which is const char *, and it can't be modified.

Comment: You can iteratively traverse up the tree to find the root node, creating a list of nodes (inserting at the front).  You can then iteratively traverse the list in sequence to print the data.  If you want to build the entire path before printing anything, you can track lengths as you go and allocate space, etc before copying the data to the right place.  If you can print the components piecemeal, don't need to track lengths or allocate any space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should have indicate what he/she has tried so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Initial Answer

Can I assume that the root node will have the parent pointer equal to `0`?

If the structure is like this:

```
struct node {
    struct node *parent;
    char *data;
    // Edit: I realize you said this would be a char, but I am trying
    //  to focus on the core of your question which is how you go
    //  up the tree to the top without recursion. You would just malloc
    //  the space you need and copy the data over into your workable
    //  space.
}
```

Then I would use a `while` loop in this way:

```
while (cur->parent != 0) {
    // malloc some space and load cur->value to an array of
    //  character arrays (array of c-strings)
    cur = cur->parent;  // move up
}
// now after we exit we just need to build the string with our array,
//  and ensure we add a leading '/' first.
```

That is the general algorithm I would use that doesn't use recursion. If you get stuck on writing the meat of the code, post your code, describe exactly what isn't working, and tell us what steps you took to debug it.

### Follow-up (malloc)

EDIT: As Jonathan correctly points out, reallocing every time can be a waste of time. Some people decide to double their array every time they need to realloc, and some expand their array by some factor or some constant. I consider these methods very useful, but outside the scope of what we're doing.

The way that you would malloc your space is by using realloc every time you need to expand. There are a thousand ways to store your data, but I would probably store the strings I pull from each node as an array of arrays. In other words:

```
char **space;
space = realloc(i+1, sizeof(*space));
  // where i tracks how many elements you've gone through
*(space + i) = malloc(strlen(me->value)*sizeof(*space));
  // Then use strcpy if possible, otherwise write a for loop and copy
  //  each char manually.
```

Comment: but how can I resize the malloc'd space as I go?

Comment: I added how I would do that. Realloc is awesome for scaling your dynamically allocated memory. You should write some code and post it though :).

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? I thought I did a reasonable job of explaining the process one would use to traverse up a tree without recursion.

Comment: Be cautious about incrementing allocated space by one each time if the array might grow large.  It can lead to quadratic time performance.  If the size will only ever be small, it won't matter.  (Often, keeping a count of the space allocated and the space in use is sufficient; when there's no spare space, double the space allocated.)

Comment: Thanks, this works

Comment: That is true, but for beginners I like to just show them how to make your memory match what you are doing to keep things straightforward. Doubling your array can also be dangerous if your array is large, as you might only need a little more space, which is why implementations often use a factor that they found balances space/speed. That seems beyond the scope of what we're doing.

Comment: @B.Li if I answered your question, feel free to mark as answer and/or upvote to counter someone's downvote that I still don't have an explanation for.